# Symfony pack symfony/apache-pack is not working

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have a problem with latest or latest LTS version of Symfony. I can't install symfony/apache-pack. The prompt where terminal should ask me a question:

```
Do you want to execute this recipe?
```

is skipped and it shows me error:

```
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.


[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
Aborted
```

I was successfully using Symfony with apache-pack on my main PC with Windows 7 and the same setup in laragon but it is not working on my laptop with Windows 10. I'm using the same commands they use in official docs. Any ideas?

Comment: Please check your logs to see if there's a more detailed error message. It could be many things. For instance the dependencies of `symfony/apache-pack` might not be met on your different laptop because it is missing a PHP extension of some sorts

Comment: Hello and thank You for Your reply. Do You mean Apache errors log, PHP error log or Symfony logs? Apache log is empty, PHP log also is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's only a terminal issue. Maybe you can try with an other terminal.

If you are not able to respond to the terminal question, there is an alternative. When you choose "p" (for permanently), your composer.json file is modified to skip this message the next time.

If you change the settings manually in your **composer.json**, the question will not be asked anymore:

```
"extra": {
     "symfony": {
        "allow-contrib": false
    }
}
```

Change this settings to true and you will be good!

This setting aims to know of you allows "contrib recipes" to be executed.

Comment: Wow, this is a true solution to my problem. By the way, can You explain why this is a terminal problem if on Windows 7 Cmder works perfectly but on Windows 10 it works like this (I can't interact with console prompts)?

Comment: I can't be sure that is it a terminal problem but to me it is like you said, that you can't interact with the console prompts.

Comment: I don't know theteminal you use but I have no issue with the Windows PowerShell. Or you can use git bash which is installed with git on windows.